# Using BeautifulSoup to extract multiple pages of data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup python package to scrape a table of data from a webpage. The tables have many pages that can be clicked through, I was hoping that i could extract each page of the table by running through adjusted URL's that identify the page but this particular site is statically updating the table using javascript that changes the source code.

Does anyone know a work-around? I am new to BeautifulSoup and do not know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: Chances are, you will need to use selenium for this.

Comment: I should also say that we'd probably need to know more. What web page is this?

Comment: @BillBell Selenium was the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome!